# Get the parentViewController instance

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes: `MyViewController: UIViewController` and `TheView: UIView`. Inside the `MyViewController` i have declared and object `var theView: TheView` and a boolean flag like `var flag: Bool = false`. How do I get the `flag` value from inside `TheView` class without passing if from `MyViewController`? I have tried methods like `if let vc = self.parentViewController as? MyViewController { }` but unsuccessfully.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having such a dependency where your UIView knows about the ViewController since this makes the modules less reusable. Have you tried the delegate pattern?

Comment: Sure, but that was first solution that came to my mind. I have commented @Samah answer where I wrote what solution I used. Btw. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it's difficult to get a reference to a view's associated controller should be a hint that it's bad practice.  You would be better off passing the parent view controller into the view's initialiser and storing it as a weak reference.

```
class TheView: UIView {
    weak var parentViewController: MyViewController?

    init(parentViewController: MyViewController) {
        self.parentViewController = parentViewController
    }
}

// in MyViewController...
let view = TheView(parentViewController: self)
```

Comment: I have accepted this as an answer because of visualising me that it's a bad practise. I have added a flag to `TheView` and set it from `MyViewController`'s instance of `theView`. Thanks!

Comment: Actually we can use parent property of UIViewController. But we need to make sure that the relation between child and root is established correctly (with addChildViewController and didMoveToParentViewController methods...)

Comment: Won't have any luck with this using storyboards ;)

Answer (score 1):

get `parentViewController` from view then use this extension.

```
extension UIView {

    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Get a `UIView` `parentViewController` like that.

```
class TheView: UIView {
    func teset(){
        if let vc = self.parentViewController as? ViewController {
            //Sccess block
        }
    }
}
```

your ParentViewController like.

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var theView: TheView = TheView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.addSubview(theView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to declare a variable in TheView that references the parent and set this when you instantiate TheView:

```
var parentController: MyViewController?
```

Then when you instantiate theView you can attach the parent:

```
// Instantiate your view either view storyboard or code and then:
self.theView.parentController = self
```